# Initializing vector in class

Tags: c++, class, vector

This piece of code works well out of class -

```
const char* list[] = {"Author: ", "Label: ", "Price: ", "Date: "};
vector<string> vlist(list, list+4);
```

but when I put it into class, it behaves like a function - compiler is giving me error "list" is not a type, error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘+’ token etc. ??

Comment: Without C++11, you'll have to use `push_back` or do that in the constructor and use `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

Common pattern is as follows:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   template<class It>
   MyClass(It beg, It end) : vec(beg,end) { }

private:
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
 };
int main() {
   std::string s[] = { "abc", "bcd" };
   MyClass c(s, s+2);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Array sizes cannot be deduced automatically in in-class initializers. Instead, you need to specify the size:

```
const char* list[4] = {"Author: ", "Label: ", "Price: ", "Date: "};
```

Your `vlist` member can be initialized from a temporary:

```
vector<string> vlist = vector<string>(list, list + 4);
```

But that can be inefficient. It's better to initialize it in the constructor instead in order to avoid temporaries.

However, are you sure you need the plain `list` array at all? Because if not, it's much easier to just do this instead:

```
vector<string> list = {"Author: ", "Label: ", "Price: ", "Date: "};
```

Also, you need to make sure you've enabled C++11 mode in your compiler. With GCC or Clang that would be the `-std=c++11` or `-std=g++11` (for GNU extensions) compiler flag.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because your class definition can't call functions, only declare them. You can use the initializer list in the class's constructor to get around this:

```
const char* list[] = { "Author: ", "Label: ", "Price: ", "Date: " };

class c
{
    vector<string> vlist;
    c() : vlist(list, list + 4) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, you can initialize your vector directly by *initializer list*:

```
vector<string> vlist {"Author: ", "Label: ", "Price: ", "Date: "};
```

If not, you have to do it in the constructor, most probably by `push_back`:

```
Class::Class() {
    vlist.push_back("Author :");
    vlist.push_back("Label :");
    vlist.push_back("Price :");
    vlist.push_back("Date :");
}
```

Anyway, there's no point in creating intermediate C-style table, if in the end you are going to use `vector`.

Comment: There is if you have 100 `push_back`s to do instead of one array initialization.

Comment: Why would you want to hard-code 100 strings? Anyway, the performance of it doesn't necessarily have to be worse.

Comment: Fine, 10. I'd still prefer not having 10 calls at that stage. You could, I don't know, hard-code a game's item names, though. There have to be some situations where you'd want a large array of strings.

Comment: And in that situation you'll want to read them from, say, XML file instead of hard-coding them, because you will have to do it sooner or later, especially in game programming. There's also probably a way to use `boost::mpl` to do it, but... I'd still say it's the correct solution. And again, copying the whole array can be slower.